# Are there any differences between the Shangri-La anime, manga, and light novel?

Tags: anime-production, shangri-la

Are there any differences between the Shangri-La anime and LN? What about the manga?

Comment: Whether it's a "good" adaptation is probably a matter of opinion, and not really something we can answer, but we can certainly list the differences and let you decide for yourself.

Comment: Sure. That's fine.